# how to insert image and data in mysql database using php source code

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, ajax, phpmyadmin

I am trying to insert images and data in my database from HTML form. I have written PHP code to accomplish this task. The program is not generating any error message, but also not inserting image data in MySQL database. Kindly check it. Here i am sharing a excerpt from my code.

```
 <?php

    error_reporting(E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE);
    @ini_set('post_max_size', '64M');
    @ini_set('upload_max_filesize', '64M');

    /* * *********************************************** */
    // database constants
    define('DB_DRIVER', 'mysql');
    define('DB_SERVER', 'localhost');
    define('DB_SERVER_USERNAME', 'remote');
    define('DB_SERVER_PASSWORD', 'remote123');
    define('DB_DATABASE', 'test');

    $dboptions = array(
        PDO::ATTR_PERSISTENT => FALSE,
        PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE => PDO::FETCH_ASSOC,
        PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION,
        PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => 'SET NAMES utf8',
    );

    try {
      $DB = new PDO(DB_DRIVER . ':host=' . DB_SERVER . ';dbname=' . DB_DATABASE, DB_SERVER_USERNAME, DB_SERVER_PASSWORD, $dboptions);
    } catch (Exception $ex) {
      echo $ex->getMessage();
      die;
    }

    if (isset($_POST["sub1"]) || isset($_POST["sub2"])) {
      // include resized library
      require_once('./php-image-magician/php_image_magician.php');
      $msg = "";
      $valid_image_check = array("image/gif", "image/jpeg", "image/jpg", "image/png", "image/bmp");
      if (count($_FILES["user_files"]) > 0) {
        $folderName = "uploads/";
        $sql = "INSERT INTO tbl_image (full_name, email, age, image_name) VALUES (:full_name, :email, :age, :img)";
       $stmt = $DB->prepare($sql);
        $query->bindParam(':full_name', $_POST['full_name'], PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $query->bindParam(':email', $_POST['email'], PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $query->bindParam(':age', $_POST['age'], PDO::PARAM_STR);

        for ($i = 0; $i < count($_FILES["user_files"]["name"]); $i++) {

          if ($_FILES["user_files"]["name"][$i] <> "") {

            $image_mime = strtolower(image_type_to_mime_type(exif_imagetype($_FILES["user_files"]["tmp_name"][$i])));
            // if valid image type then upload
            if (in_array($image_mime, $valid_image_check)) {

              $ext = explode("/", strtolower($image_mime));
              $ext = strtolower(end($ext));
              $filename = rand(10000, 990000) . '_' . time() . '.' . $ext;
              $filepath = $folderName . $filename;

              if (!move_uploaded_file($_FILES["user_files"]["tmp_name"][$i], $filepath)) {
                $emsg .= "Failed to upload <strong>" . $_FILES["user_files"]["name"][$i] . "</strong>. <br>";
                $counter++;
              } else {
                $smsg .= "<strong>" . $_FILES["user_files"]["name"][$i] . "</strong> uploaded successfully. <br>";

                $magicianObj = new imageLib($filepath);
                $magicianObj->resizeImage(100, 100);
                $magicianObj->saveImage($folderName . 'thumb/' . $filename, 100);

                /*             * ****** insert into database starts ******** */
                try {
                  $stmt->bindValue(":img", $filename);
                  $stmt->execute();
                  $result = $stmt->rowCount();
                  if ($result > 0) {
                    // file uplaoded successfully.
                  } else {
                    // failed to insert into database.
                  }
                } catch (Exception $ex) {
                  $emsg .= "<strong>" . $ex->getMessage() . "</strong>. <br>";
                }
                /*             * ****** insert into database ends ******** */
              }
            } else {
              $emsg .= "<strong>" . $_FILES["user_files"]["name"][$i] . "</strong> not a valid image. <br>";
            }
          }
        }


        $msg .= (strlen($smsg) > 0) ? successMessage($smsg) : "";
        $msg .= (strlen($emsg) > 0) ? errorMessage($emsg) : "";
      } else {
        $msg = errorMessage("You must upload atleast one file");
      }
    }
    ?>
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
      <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
        <link rel="icon" href="" type="image/x-icon" />
        <!--iOS/android/handheld specific -->
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <meta name="description" content="Upload multiple images create thumbnails and save path to database with php and mysql">
        <meta name="keywords" content="php, mysql, thumbnail,upload image, check mime type">
        <meta name="author" content="Shahrukh Khan">
        <title>Upload multiple images create thumbnails and save path to database with php and mysql - thesoftwareguy</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" type="text/css" />
        <style>
          .files{height: 30px; margin: 10px 10px 0 0;width: 250px; }
          .add{ font-size: 14px; color: #EB028F; border: none; }
          .rem a{ font-size: 14px; color: #f00; border: none; }
          .submit{width: 110px; height: 30px; background: #6D37B0; color: #fff;text-align: center;}
        </style>
        <script src="jquery-1.9.0.min.js"></script>
        <script>
          $(document).ready(function() {
            $(".add").click(function() {
              $('<div><input class="files" name="user_files[]" type="file" ><span class="rem" ><a href="javascript:void(0);" >Remove</span></div>').appendTo(".contents");

            });
            $('.contents').on('click', '.rem', function() {
              $(this).parent("div").remove();
            });

          });
        </script>
      </head>
      <body>
        <div id="container">
          <div id="body">
            <div class="mainTitle" >Upload multiple images create thumbnails and save path to database with php and mysql</div>
            <div class="height20"></div>
            <article>
              <?php echo $msg; ?>
              <div class="height20"></div>
              <div style="width: 380px; margin: 0 auto;">
                <h3 style="text-align: center;">Image will be resized to 100px X 100px </h3>
                <form name="f1" action="index.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">            
                  <fieldset>
                    <legend>Demo1</legend>
                    Attach multiple Files:
                    <input class="files" name="user_files[]" type="file" multiple="multiple" >
                    <div class="height10"></div>
                    <div><input type="submit" class="submit" name="sub1" value="Upload Images" /> </div>
                  </fieldset> 
                </form>
                <div style="width: 380px; margin: 0 auto;">
                  <form name="f2" action="index.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                    <fieldset>
                      <legend>Demo2</legend>
                         <input type="text" id="full_name" class="frm_input" placeholder="Full name">
                        <input type="text" id="email" class="frm_input" placeholder="Email">
                        <input type="text" id="age" class="frm_input" placeholder="Age">
                      <input class="files" name="user_files[]" type="file" ><span><a href="javascript:void(0);" class="add" >Add More</a></span>
                      <div class="contents"></div>
                      <div class="height10"></div>
                      <div><input type="submit" class="submit" name="sub2" value="Upload Images" /> </div>
                    </fieldset>
                  </form>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="height10"></div>
              <?php
              // fetch all records
              $sql = "SELECT * FROM tbl_image WHERE 1 ";
              try {
                $stmt = $DB->prepare($sql);
                $stmt->execute();
                $images = $stmt->fetchAll();
              } catch (Exception $ex) {
                echo $ex->getMessage();
              }
              ?>
               <ul class="reorder_ul reorder-photos-list">
              <table class="bordered">
                <tr><th>ID</th><th>thumbnail</th><th>ORIGINAL</th></tr>
                <?php
                if (count($images) > 0) {
                  foreach ($images as $img) {
                    ?>


                      <li id="image_li_<?php echo $count; ?>" class="ui-sortable-handle">
                      <p><?php echo $img["image_name"]; ?></p>
                        <a href="uploads/<?php echo $img["image_name"]; ?>" target="_blank">
                          <img src="uploads/<?php echo $img["image_name"]; ?>" alt="<?php echo $img["image_name"]; ?>" width="300" height="300">
                        </a>
                        <p><?php echo $rs['full_name']; ?></p>
                    <p><?php echo $rs['email']; ?></p>
                    <p><?php echo $rs['age']; ?></p>
                    <p><a href="#" class="delete_m" onclick="delete_member(<?php echo $rs['id']; ?>)"><img src="images/delete.png"> Delete</a></td>
                      </li>

                    <?php
                  }
                } else {
                  ?>
                   <tr>
                  <td colspan="3">No images in the database.</td>
                </tr> 
                <?php } ?>
              </table>
               </ul>
              <div class="height10"></div>
            </article>
            <div class="height10"></div>
            <footer>
              <div class="copyright"> &copy; 2013 <a href="http://www.thesoftwareguy.in" target="_blank">thesoftwareguy</a>. All rights reserved </div>
              <div class="footerlogo"><a href="http://www.thesoftwareguy.in" target="_blank"><img src="http://www.thesoftwareguy.in/thesoftwareguy-logo-small.png" width="200" height="47" alt="thesoftwareguy logo" /></a> </div>
            </footer>
          </div>
        </div>

      </body>
    </html>
    <?php

    function errorMessage($str) {
      return '<div style="width:50%; margin:0 auto; border:2px solid #F00;padding:2px; color:#000; margin-top:10px; text-align:center;">' . $str . '</div>';
    }

    function successMessage($str) {
      return '<div style="width:50%; margin:0 auto; border:2px solid #06C;padding:2px; color:#000; margin-top:10px; text-align:center;">' . $str . '</div>';
    }
    ?>
```

Comment: There is too much code that is irrelevant for your question. Please check http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve and update your question.

Comment: Sunil, you've been provided with an answer below. Take it up with them. I am leaving this question. Good luck.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
   insert image and data in mysql database using php source code and view the images.  



 <?php


            $images_arr = array();
                //This is the directory where images will be saved
            $target_dir = "uploads/";
            $target = $target_dir.$_FILES['photo']['name'];

                //$target = $target . basename( $_FILES['photo']['name']);

                //This gets all the other information from the form
            $name=$_POST['nameMember'];
            $bandMember=$_POST['bandMember'];
            $pic=($_FILES['photo']['name']);
            $about=$_POST['aboutMember'];
            $bands=$_POST['otherBands'];


                // Connects to your Database
            mysql_connect("Localhost", "remote", "remote123") or die(mysql_error()) ;
            mysql_select_db("test") or die(mysql_error()) ;

                //Writes the information to the database
            mysql_query("INSERT INTO dbProfiles (nameMember,bandMember,photo,aboutMember,otherBands)
            VALUES ('$name', '$bandMember', '$pic', '$about', '$bands')") ;

            //Writes the photo to the server
            if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['photo']['tmp_name'], $target)){

                    //Tells you if its all ok
                echo "The file ". $target_dir.$_FILES['photo']['name']. " has been uploaded, and your information has been added to the directory";
                $images_arr[] = $target;
            }
            else {

                //Gives and error if its not
                echo "Sorry, there was a problem uploading your file.";
            }

    ?>
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
        <head>
            <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
            <link rel="icon" href="http://www.thesoftwareguy.in/favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon" />
                    <!--iOS/android/handheld specific -->
            <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
            <meta name="description" content="Upload multiple images create thumbnails and save path to database with php and mysql">
            <meta name="keywords" content="php, mysql, thumbnail,upload image, check mime type">
            <meta name="author" content="Shahrukh Khan">
            <title>Upload multiple images create thumbnails and save path to database with php and mysql </title>
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" type="text/css" />
            <style>
                 .files{height: 30px; margin: 10px 10px 0 0;width: 250px; }
                .add{ font-size: 14px; color: #EB028F; border: none; }
                .rem a{ font-size: 14px; color: #f00; border: none; }
                .submit{width: 110px; height: 30px; background: #6D37B0; color: #fff;text-align: center;}
            </style>
            <script src="jquery-1.9.0.min.js"></script>
            <script>
                $(document).ready(function() {
                    $(".add").click(function() {
                    $('<div><input class="files" name="user_files[]" type="file" ><span class="rem" ><a href="javascript:void(0);" >Remove</span></div>').appendTo(".contents");

                    });
                    $('.contents').on('click', '.rem', function() {
                    $(this).parent("div").remove();
                    });

                });
            </script>
        </head>
        <body>
            <form name="f1" action="index.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">  
                <input type="hidden" name="image_form_submit" value="1"/>
                    <div id="container">
                        <div id="body">
                            <div class="mainTitle" >Upload multiple images create thumbnails and save path to database with php and mysql</div>
                            <div class="height20"></div>
                            <article>
                                <div class="height20"></div>
                                <div style="width: 380px; margin: 0 auto;">
                                    <h3 style="text-align: center;">Image will be resized to 100px X 100px </h3>

                                    <p>Please Enter the Band Members Name.</p>
                                    <p> Band Member or Affiliates Name:</p>
                                    <input type="text" name="nameMember"/>
                                    <p>
                                         Please Enter the Band Members Position. Example:Drums.
                                    </p>
                                     <p>
                                        Band Position:
                                     </p>
                                    <input type="text" name="bandMember"/>
                                    <p>
                                        Please Upload a Photo of the Member in gif or jpeg format. The file name should be named after the Members name. If the same file name is uploaded twice it will be overwritten! Maxium size of File is 35kb.
                                    </p>
                                    <p>
                                        Photo:
                                    </p>
                                    <input type="hidden" name="size" value="350000">
                                    <input type="file" name="photo"> 
                                <p>
                                    Please Enter any other information about the band member here.
                                </p>
                                <p>
                                     Other Member Information:
                                </p>
                                <textarea rows="10" cols="35" name="aboutMember">
                                </textarea>
                                 <p>
                                     Please Enter any other Bands the Member has been in.
                                 </p>
                                <p>
                                         Other Bands:
                                </p>
                                    <input type="text" name="otherBands" size=30 />
                                <br/>
                                <br/>
                                    <input TYPE="submit" name="upload" title="Add data to the Database" value="Add Member"/>




                            </div>
                            <table class="bordered">
                             <?php
              // fetch all records
              $sql = "SELECT * FROM dbProfiles WHERE 1 "; ?>
              <?php
             $sql="SELECT * FROM dbProfiles";
     $result_set=mysql_query($sql);
     while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result_set))
     {
      ?>
            <tr>
           <td><p><?php echo $row['nameMember'] ?>"</p></td>
            <td><img src="uploads/<?php echo $row['photo'] ?>" width="200px" height="200px;"/><p><?php echo $row['nameMember'] ?>"</p></td>
            </tr>
            <?php
     }
     ?>
     </table>

                        </article>
                    </div>

                </div>
                <div class="height10"></div>

        </form>

      </body>
    </html>
    <?php

    function errorMessage($str) {
      return '<div style="width:50%; margin:0 auto; border:2px solid #F00;padding:2px; color:#000; margin-top:10px; text-align:center;">' . $str . '</div>';
    }

    function successMessage($str) {
      return '<div style="width:50%; margin:0 auto; border:2px solid #06C;padding:2px; color:#000; margin-top:10px; text-align:center;">' . $str . '</div>';
    }
    ?>
```

Answer (score -1):

Your file field should be like `<input type="file" name="img" multiple>`  and I hope you will not face any issue after it.

Comment: incorrect. read the manual http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.multiple.php `multiple="multiple"` is valid. You missed something.

Comment: that isn't the official PHP.net documentation. w3 schools is awful. I'll eat my shorts if the OP agrees with you. Deal?

Comment: *"both will work in same way"* - you're contradicting yourself. Look at what the OP is already using `<input class="files" name="user_files[]" type="file" multiple="multiple" >` the only one that I could tell that "might" fail, is the one in their JS version `$('<div><input class="files" name="user_files[]" type="file" >` but I doubt that.

Comment: try to work on both and you will not find any difference between them . just test both on your side you will be clear with it

Comment: I just test now and both input types are  working fine. i am not contradicting. i suggest you if you think i am wrong with this answer just test on your side .

Comment: fair enough. I removed my downvote. OP will need to interact with everyone here.